# Product of all digits of an integer number C#

Tags: c#, recursion

I am attempting to write a recursive program that will take user inputted number then have the program be able to calculate the product of all digits of the integer. I have worked out how I want the program to run, but am unable to work out how I should run my loop to calculate the product of all the digits. I have found out that you can do this in the language c by using num%10 which retrieves the last digit of num, and num/10 to peel off one digit at a time from the end of the integer. I am just unable to work out how I could implement this in C# and how the if/else structure should be.

Below is my code I have written for the program already aside from writing code for the of the if/else statement. If anybody would be able to point me in the right direction of how to achieve this, that would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Console;

namespace _3
{
class Tester
 {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int length;
        Write("Enter a number: ");
        string num = Console.ReadLine();
        length = num.Length;
        int productofnum = Int32.Parse(num);
        productofnum = CalcProduct(productofnum);
        WriteLine("The product of all digits of the number {0} is {1}.",num, productofnum);
    }
    public static int CalcProduct(int num)
    {
        int length = num.ToString().Length;
        if (length == 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {
        }
        return num;
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first when using a recursive function you shouldn't have any loops inside.

You built the structure of the method almost correctly but it need a bit changes:

```
public static int CalcProduct(int num)
{
    int length = num.ToString().Length;
    if (length == 1)
    {
        return num;
    }
    return (num % 10) * CalcProduct(num / 10);
}
```

Explanation:

When using a recursive function usually you need to call the function you are using in the return - so it would be recursive read more at [Recursive methods using C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142292/Recursive-methods-in-Csharp).

Comment: Great works how I want it to!

Regarding recursion, coud I just ask though, I have been told that a loop would be necessary in recursion as the if (is the "Base Case") and the else (recursive case) must work toward making the base case true e.g. this is an exmple that I have found in its most simple form of recursion:

https://paste.ofcode.org/k6LNEqJNBGVm6k9uZxxEVU

Microsoft on recursion which I think is stating that what I said above is true.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3dk2cc3(v=vs.100).aspx#Using Recursion

Could your answer be made like how the article describes?

Comment: First I believe this was the hard part to write and that all the other things are necessary but they weren't your main problem. Second notice that SO Isn't a site so people will solve your homework (thats why you got 2 negative votes). Now you are able and should continue by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of Yonlif's answer: If you wish your program to also be able to work with negative numbers, don't forget to use Math.Abs(num) before using div and mod. Something like this:

```
public static int CalcProduct(int num)
{
    int _num=Math.Abs(num);
    int length = _num.ToString().Length;
    if (length == 1)
    {
        return _num;
    }
    return (_num % 10) * CalcProduct(_num / 10);
}
```

Also, here is the tail recursive method, should you prefer it:

```
private  static int CalcProductTailRecHelper(int num, int res)
{
   int length = num.ToString().Length;
   if (length == 1)
   {
       return res;
   }
   return CalcProductTailRecHelper(num / 10, res*(num % 10));
}

private  static int CalcProductTailRec(int num){
    CalcProductTailRecHelper(Math.Abs(num), 1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I forgot it when I wrote the answer.